# DataGridView row formatting based on hidden column

Tags: winforms, datagridview

Is there any way to set the style of a row based on some value from a column that is not visible to the user? The grid contains a couple of rows and I want some rows to be colored in red if they were deleted. I have a hidden column that stores true if the columns were deleted, false otherwise. I've tried `CellFormatting` but since my column is not visible, `e.ColumnIndex` never has the correct value for my hidden column.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Below is an image of what I am trying to accomplish. You can see that the second row has the text red which is due to the values in a column that the user cannot see in the datagrid. This grid should be colored like this when the user see the form for the first time too (on load).

[image]

Comment: please post a MCVE. a picture of expected result would be helpful as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `CellFormatting`, try `CellValueChanged` for unbound data or `DataBindingComplete` for a bound data set. For example, let's say that you are "deleting/undeleting" a row using the following `Button.Click` event:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool value = (bool)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Deleted"].Value;
    dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Deleted"].Value = !value;

    // For bound data (like a DataTable) add the following line:
    // ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).AcceptChanges();
}
```

**Unbound Data**

Changing the rows "deleted" column value in this way will trigger the following event handler. Therefore, you can color your row based on that column's value of `True` or `False`:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Deleted"].Index)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = (bool)dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
    }
}
```

**Bound Data**

For bound data, such as from a `DataTable`, handling the `DataBindingComplete` event will be enough. This event will trigger when the binding is first set as well as after changes - such as the changes from the `Button1.Click` event. Here, you'll loop through the rows and set the desired style according to the hidden column's value. *(Note the additional change to the `Button1_Click` event handler for a grid with a `DataTable` source. This is needed to give an immediate style change - otherwise it won't happen until you navigate to a different row.)*

```
private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.DefaultSCellStyle.ForeColor = (bool)row.Cells["Deleted"].Value ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Comment: I look for this answer an entire day :(( I found a lot of incomplete answers of the same problem. Thank you @OhBeWise

Comment: @ValiMaties Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you want to get a column's value when the column is a invisible column in DataGridView.

Is it right? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    dataGridView1.DataSource = CreateDataTable();  
    dataGridView1.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;  // Set the ID column invisible.  
    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells["ID"].Value.ToString()); // Get the ID column value.
}
```

Comment: I need to color some rows based on some values in a column that is not visible in dataGridView. I can get the value, but I want to use some event to color the rows.