# Coloring a row in a datagridview based on a hidden column

Tags: visual-studio-2015, datagridview, formatting, backcolor

Is it possible to apply a background color to a row in a datagridview based on the value of a hidden column?

Currently I use this bit of code to apply formatting...

```
Private Sub caselist_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles caselist.CellFormatting
    Try
        If e.ColumnIndex = caselist.Columns("highlight").Index Then
            If e.Value.ToString = 4 Then
                caselist.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Aquamarine
                caselist.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
            ElseIf e.Value.ToString = 5 Then
                caselist.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
            End If
         End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

So if column 'Highlight' has a value of 4 or 5, the corresponding color is applied. However, this relies on that highlight column being visible on the DGV.
If I hide the column with `caselist.Columns(0).Visible = False` then sure, the column is hidden but the formatting is not applied.

I'd love to not have to show a random number in a column at the start of my DGV.

Any help appriciated :)

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37944123/3773066).  I provided an answer to the linked question in C#, but [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com) can help.

Comment: As OhBeWise suggest, it appears you are using the wrong event for what you are trying to do. The “CellFormatting” event is for formatting a “displayed” cell after some event. You may want to consider that if a cell is NOT visible and its value changes… then `CellFormatting` will not fire because there is nothing to format as formatting is for “displayed” cells. It does not make sense to repaint a cell that is not visible.

Comment: You do not say when or how these non-visible cells are populated nor do you state if they are changed anytime later through some programmatic way… i.e. a button click. If the data is read in once and is static, then no event is needed, simply loop through the grid after the data source has been set, then change each row accordingly. If the cells values are changed programmatically after the data source has been set, then you will need an event like `CellValueChanged` where you could color the row accordingly when the cells value changes.

Comment: However… Since the cells you are examining are NOT visible… I can safely assume the USER will NEVER change these values… Therefore… If you are changing these values programmatically individually or as a group, it would appear that when you change the cells values it might also be a good time to color the row(s). This avoids having to set up any event for the grid. In other words, you KNOW you want to change the rows color when you change these values; an event for the grid seems unnecessary. Just a thought.